# Is using ProgressDialog recommended for login?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, authentication, progressdialog

I have a login activity where once the login button is pressed a http request will be sent to an api to verify the credentials.

The problem I face is that the button can be pressed multiple times and getting a response back from this task can sometimes take a while.

My solution was to add a ProgressDialog to block the UI. However, I come to find out that ProgressDialog is deprecated. I did some research and it seems that the reason it was deprecated was exactly because the blocking of UI is not optimal for most scenarios.

So I ask, is using ProgressDialog recommended for login scenarios? If not, what would be the best method to handle a login activity when getting a response back from the API may take longer than expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom "Button" with a disabled/enabled state. When the user clicks the button use disable the button, clear the text and show the progress bar.

I think this one is a more elegant way to show the loading progress.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Connect"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```